# Difference between two conditional sentences

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the difference in the meaning  between following sentences:

1.If I'm to be a teacher , I will never be absent from school. (I have found in a grammar book that It's called indicative mood)

2.If I become a teacher, I will never be absent from school.

The sentences above are quite similar to me ,I'm a bit familarized with 2nd sentence but I'm confused to guess the meaning of 1st sentence. There is the use of 'am to be '  What kind of sentence structure it is? And how it's different from 2nd sentence? Please explain in details.

Comment: The first sentence looks ungrammatical to me. "If I'm to be a teacher" suggests that what follows is a necessary condition for me to become a teacher. "I will..." does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences are subtly different.

**If I'm to be a teacher...** is a hypothetical statement about a *possibility, intent, or expectation for the future*.  You could read it as being like "if I am *intended* to be a teacher..." or "if I am *expected* to become a teacher..."  As such, it's really a statement about the present, because the intention is in the present - note that it's "if I am", not "if I will be"!  Therefore, the second part of the sentence, "...I will never be absent from school", doesn't really match, because it's in the future tense.
 I can think of some cases where the future *will* would be appropriate, for example

> If I am expected to cook dinner tonight, I will need someone else to get the kids from school.

I think this sort of future *will* is used mainly to express something that makes the hypothetical possible in the future, as in "I will need someone else to get the kids from school (in order to make it possible for me to cook dinner)." But in your sentence, never being absent isn't something that makes being a teacher possible; it doesn't make sense to say "... I will never be absent in order to make it possible for me to be a teacher."

**If I become a teacher...** is a hypothetical statement about *changing into something else in the future*, so "will never be" makes more sense here - it's like "If I do X, then I will do Y."

---

The "am to be" part is an unusual but correct phrasing.  The general pattern is "*noun BE* to *verb-phrase*".  For example, you might say

> I am to visit them on Monday
>
> You are to take all the medicine
>
> She is to be sworn in as judge next week
>
> He was to have been crowned king

The phrasing means that there is an expectation or intention of the verb phrase.

Comment: Sir, I've found in a grammar book that the first sentence is in indicative found, which you said  partly wrong but I think it's not wrong

Comment: Please reply me

Comment: I've a grammar book. According to the grammar book, 1st sentence is in indicative mood and Express 'supposition' as fact. BUt i'm not understanding what it means, your answer hasn't yet addressed it, so, please edit your answer

Comment: Does your grammar book actually say that the 1st sentence is indicative?!  [Because it looks like the subjunctive, which is used for imaginary things or things that are contrary to fact, and is often used with *if*.](http://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/)  I don't understand the rest of your questions.  "which you said partly wrong" - what did I say was wrong?  I am talking about matching "I will" with the present tense "I am", not about moods.  And what exactly about the first sentence do you not understand?

Comment: Looks correct to me (a native speaker).